# File Upload Issue Android WebView

Tags: php, android, mysql, webview, android-webview

How to upload an image to MySQL database from android WebView using PHP ? I have already implemented a file picker for choosing image from our device.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this demo example
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" name="upload">upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{   
     
 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="upload/";
 
 /* new file size in KB */
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 /* new file size in KB */
 
 /* make file name in lower case */
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 /* make file name in lower case */
 
 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
 
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO image(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  
 
  echo "File sucessfully upload";
        
  
 }
 else
 {
  
  echo "Error.Please try again";
        
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks